# Coderivative of symmetric $2$-tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors, multilinear-algebra

This is taken from a paper by M. Berger:

[image: excerpt]

Here $(X,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold and $h$ is a symmetric $2$-tensor on $X$. Could you help me to understand this definition, please? What does $\nabla^k$ mean?

Is it correct to say that if $\{ E_1, \dots , E_n\}$ is a local orthonormal frame, then

$$(\delta h)_i = - \sum_k E_k(h(E_k, E_i)) \quad ?$$

Comment: Have you figured it out already? If not, give me a few hours and I can answer this thoroughly.

Comment: This is (up to a normalization constant) the adjoint of the Killing operator written in [abstract index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation).  It is obtained by taking the covariant derivative and then contracting as indicated by the repeated index $k$.  This is not the same as your last display.

Comment: I have no clue how to interpret Berger’s notation.

Comment: In index notation, contractions are normally taken after derivatives, which would instead give$$(\delta h)(E_i)=-\sum_k(\nabla h)(E_k,E_k,E_i)$$

Comment: $\nabla h$ is the covariant derivative of the symmetric $2$-tensor $h$. $\nabla h$ is a $3$-tensor, so it is a multilinear function of 3 tangent vectors, two for $h$ itself and one for the covarient derivative. You can write $\nabla h = \nabla_kh_{ij}dx^k\otimes(dx^i\circ dx^j)$. Then $\delta h$ is the $1$-tensor obtained by taking a trace. The formula is given by @Kajelad. If you use local coordinates instead of an orthonormal frame, then, if $h = h(\partial_j, \partial_k)dx^j\circ dx^k$, then $$\delta h = g^{jk}(\nabla h(\partial_j, \partial_k, \partial_i))\,dx^i$$

Comment: @Kajelad I think your expression ends up being the same as mine, because $\nabla_{E_i} E_j = 0$ at the center of a geodesic frame. Since $\delta h$ is a tensor, this shows that the expressions coincide everywhere.

Comment: @EduardoLonga This is not the case: $\delta h$ and $\nabla h$ are tensors, but the expression $E_i(h(E_j,E_k))$ does not depend tensorially on $E_i,E_j,E_k$ , so the expression $\sum_k E_k(h(E_k,E_i))=\sum_k(\nabla h)(E_k,E_k,E_i)$ will not hold in all local orthonormal frames.